# Import React component from local npm package return empty object

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack

I was building my first npm package of a react component.

After I build it successfully with webpack, I tried to test it with `npm link`.

It connected but the component didn't load. It gives me a bunch of errors like this

> Uncaught Error: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

So I tried to `console.log()` the component. It returns an empty `Object`.

I'm struggling with this for 2 days and have no idea what went wrong.

Here's some of the configurations

webpack.config.js

```js
var path = require("path");
const isDevelopment = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development'
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin')

module.exports = {
    mode: "production",
    entry: {
        index: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.tsx')
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: isDevelopment ? '[name].css' : '[name].[hash].css',
            chunkFilename: isDevelopment ? '[id].css' : '[id].[hash].css'
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: 'ts-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                options: { allowTsInNodeModules: true }
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: ["style-loader", "css-loader"],
            },
            {
                test: /\.module\.s[ac]ss$/,
                use: [
                    isDevelopment ? 'style-loader': MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    {
                        loader: 'css-loader',
                        options: {
                            modules: true,
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            sourceMap: isDevelopment
                        }
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.s[ac]ss$/i,
                exclude: /\.module.(s[ac]ss)$/,
                use: [
                    // Creates `style` nodes from JS strings
                    isDevelopment ? 'style-loader': MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    // to generate a .d.ts module
                    "css-modules-typescript-loader",
                    // Translates CSS into CommonJS
                    {loader: "css-loader", options: {modules: true}},
                    // Compiles Sass to CSS
                    {loader: "sass-loader", options: {sourceMap: isDevelopment}},
                ],
            },
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".css", ".scss"]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].js',
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    },
}
```

tsconfig.json

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./dist/",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationMap": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "noEmit": false,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "plugins": [{"name": "typescript-plugin-css-modules"}]
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "react-dissolve",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A color and image animated dissolve effect.",
  "main": "./dist/index.js",
  "types": "./dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist",
    "src"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "webpack"
  },
  "author": "jack szeto",
  "license": "MIT",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.16.5",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.16.5",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/color-string": "^1.5.2",
    "@types/jest": "^27.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^16.11.15",
    "@types/node-sass": "^4.11.2",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.37",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.11",
    "color-string": "^1.9.0",
    "css-loader": "^6.5.1",
    "css-modules-typescript-loader": "^4.0.1",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "^2.4.5",
    "node-sass": "^7.0.1",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-p5": "^1.3.24",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.45.1",
    "sass-loader": "^12.4.0",
    "simplex-noise": "^3.0.0",
    "style-loader": "^3.3.1",
    "ts-loader": "^9.2.6",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2",
    "webpack": "^5.65.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.9.1"
  },
  "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-p5": "^1.3.24",
    "simplex-noise": "^3.0.0",
    "color-string": "^1.9.0",
    "rc-slider": "^9.7.5",
    "sass": "^1.45.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {}
}
```

The build was put in the `dist` folder and it seems to perfect success build in the dist.

**Screenshot:**

[image]

**Minimal reproduction case:**

by using the same configuration above. I created a test project(see structure below).

I ran `npm run build` to build the component with **webpack**.

Then `npm link` to link the test project to a new ts React project. Tried to import but it produced the same error.

use case

```
import Test from 'npm-test';
...
<Test />
```

file structure

```
npm-test/
  dist/
  node_modules/
  src/
    declarations.d.ts
    index.tsx
    style.module.scss
  .babelrc
  .gitgnore
  .npmignore
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  webpack.config.js
```

index.tsx

```
import React, { CSSProperties } from 'react'
import styles from './style.module.scss';

interface TestProps {
    className?: string,
    style?: CSSProperties,
}
const Test = ({className, style}:TestProps) => {
    return (
        <div className={`${styles.test} ${className}`}
            style={{...style}}
        >
            Test
        </div>
    )
}
export default Test;
```

exported index.d.ts

```
import { CSSProperties } from 'react';
interface TestProps {
    className?: string;
    style?: CSSProperties;
}
declare const Test: ({ className, style }: TestProps) => JSX.Element;
export default Test;
//# sourceMappingURL=index.d.ts.map
```

Thanks for reading the long post!

Comment: Um, can you post your actual *code*? We'd need to see your component definition, how it's exported, how you're calling it, etc. Also, unless you really want to support old IE I would set your output to ES2015 or later, going es5 will usually *significantly* increase the size of your compiled artifact.

Comment: @JaredSmith thanks for replying. I just added the index.d.ts in the question. the actual code may be too long to put here. And if I copy and paste the whole component to the project, it works perfectly.

Comment: You need to create a [*minimal* reproduction case](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that still shows the problem. *Especially* if the actual code is too long.

Comment: really appreciate your guidance. I try my best to create a minimal reproduction case with the same configuration. let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Can you show the contents of the *compiled* file from the minimal repro case? I'd also start stripping down the minimal case until it works correctly. Comment out the styles. Compile with TS and verify the outputed file exports your function components. Remove the webpack plugins that aren't necessary to compile your "hello world" component. Run it through webpack, verify the output file is exporting your FC correctly. Start adding stuff back in one thing at a time until it breaks, last thing you add is the culprit.

Comment: the compiled file is an ugly js file. Do you really want to see it? Im gonna try your suggested approach. Wish me luck

Comment: Good luck. Don't forget that you can pretty-print the compiled file in your IDE before posting, and you don't need to post the whole thing, just the exports (and the definition of the thing it's exporting)

Comment: no luck... so right before I pass out, I noticed that the *compiled* file didn't export anything from my component.

Comment: Yeah. Something is happening during the compilation process and is screwing stuff up. Try compiling via tsc without using webpack. If it works, then it's a problem with webpack. Strip out the webpack plugins etc like in my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved the problem. Thanks @JaredSmith for helping me.

I messed around with **webpack** but finally, I decided to move on with **rollup** which is much easier to use.

Found the [Rollup tutorial by Portexe](https://youtu.be/hf6Z8OZanec) and it's very helpful.

So I changed the file structure to this

```
npm-test-hellow-world/
  src/
    component/
      hello-world.tsx
    index.ts
  .babelrc
  .gitgnore
  .npmignore
  package.json
  tsconfig.json
  rollup.config.js
```

Since in `hello-world.tsx` the function component is exported as default

```
declare const HelloWorld: React.FC<HelloWorldProps>;
export default HelloWorld;
```

Somehow the compiler didn't export the component. So I put it in the `src/component/` folder and export it from `src/index.ts`

```
export {default} from './component/hello-world';
// notice: 
// export * from './component/hello-world';
// didn't work
```

and it works! Not really sure why tho. If someone could explain it, I'll much appreciate it.

If you want to see more detail, you can check out [the GitHub repo](https://github.com/jack-szeto/react-dissolve)